# Error message "MemoryError" in Python

Tags: python, memory-management

Here's my problem: I'm trying to parse a big text file (about 15,000 KB) and write it to a MySQL database. I'm using Python 2.6, and the script parses about half the file and adds it to the database before freezing up. Sometimes it displays the text:

> MemoryError.

Other times it simply freezes. I figured I could avoid this problem by using generator's wherever possible, but I was apparently wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

When I press [Ctrl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key) + <kbd>C</kbd> to keyboard interrupt, it shows this error message:

```
...
sucessfully added vote # 2281
sucessfully added vote # 2282
sucessfully added vote # 2283
sucessfully added vote # 2284
floorvotes_db.py:35: Warning: Data truncated for column 'vote_value' at row 1
  r['bill ID']  , r['last name'], r['vote'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "floorvotes_db.py", line 67, in addAllFiles
    addFile(file)
  File "floorvotes_db.py", line 61, in addFile
    add(record)
  File "floorvotes_db.py", line 35, in add
    r['bill ID']  , r['last name'], r['vote'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulte     rrorhandler
KeyboardInterrupt


import os, re, datetime, string

# Data
DIR  = '/mydir'
tfn = r'C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\data.txt'
rgxs = {
    'bill number': {
        'rgx': r'(A|S)[0-9]+-?[A-Za-z]* {50}'}
    }

# Compile rgxs for speediness
for rgx in rgxs: rgxs[rgx]['rgx'] = re.compile(rgxs[rgx]['rgx'])
splitter = rgxs['bill number']['rgx']

# Guts
class floor_vote_file:

    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.iterdata = (str for str in
                         splitter.split(open(fn).read())
                         if str and str <> 'A' and str <> 'S')

    def iterVotes(self):
        for record in self.data:
            if record: yield billvote(record)

class billvote(object):

    def __init__(self, section):
        self.data    = [line.strip() for line
                        in section.splitlines()]
        self.summary = self.data[1].split()
        self.vtlines = self.data[2:]
        self.date    = self.date()
        self.year    = self.year()
        self.votes   = self.parse_votes()
        self.record = self.record()

    # Parse summary date
    def date(self):
        d = [int(str) for str in self.summary[0].split('/')]
        return datetime.date(d[2],d[0],d[1]).toordinal()

    def year(self):
        return datetime.date.fromordinal(self.date).year

    def session(self):
        """
        arg: 2-digit year int
        returns: 4-digit session
        """
        def odd():
            return divmod(self.year, 2)[1] == 1

        if odd():
            return str(string.zfill(self.year, 2)) + \
                   str(string.zfill(self.year + 1, 2))
        else:
            return str(string.zfill(self.year - 1, 2))+ \
                   str(string.zfill(self.year, 2))

    def house(self):
        if self.summary[2] == 'Assembly': return 1
        if self.summary[2] == 'Senate'  : return 2

    def splt_v_line(self, line):
        return [string for string in line.split('   ')
                if string <> '']

    def splt_v(self, line):
        return line.split()

    def prse_v(self, item):
        """takes split_vote item"""
        return {
            'vote'     : unicode(item[0]),
            'last name': unicode(' '.join(item[1:]))
            }

    # Parse votes - main
    def parse_votes(self):
        nested = [[self.prse_v(self.splt_v(vote))
                   for vote in self.splt_v_line(line)]
                  for line in self.vtlines]
        flattened = []
        for lst in nested:
            for dct in lst:
                flattened.append(dct)
        return flattened

    # Useful data objects
    def record(self):
        return {
            'date'    : unicode(self.date),
            'year'    : unicode(self.year),
            'session' : unicode(self.session()),
            'house'   : unicode(self.house()),
            'bill ID' : unicode(self.summary[1]),
            'ayes'    : unicode(self.summary[5]),
            'nays'    : unicode(self.summary[7]),
            }

    def iterRecords(self):

        for vote in self.votes:
            r = self.record.copy()
            r['vote']      = vote['vote']
            r['last name'] = vote['last name']
            yield r

test = floor_vote_file(tfn)


import MySQLdb as dbapi2
import floorvotes_parse as v
import os

# Initial database crap
db = dbapi2.connect(db=r"db",
                    user="user",
                    passwd="XXXXX")
cur = db.cursor()

if db and cur: print "\nConnected to db.\n"

def commit(): db.commit()

def ext():
    cur.close()
    db.close()
    print "\nConnection closed.\n"

# DATA

DIR  = '/mydir'
files = [DIR+fn for fn in os.listdir(DIR)
         if fn.startswith('fvote')]

# Add stuff
def add(r):
    """add a record"""
    cur.execute(
u'''INSERT INTO ny_votes (vote_house, vote_date, vote_year, bill_id,
member_lastname, vote_value) VALUES
(%s            , %s       , %s          ,
 %s            , %s       , %s      )''',
(r['house']    , r['date']     , r['year'],
 r['bill ID']  , r['last name'], r['vote'])
)

    #print "added", r['year'], r['bill ID']

def crt():
    """create table"""
    SQL = """
CREATE TABLE ny_votes (openleg_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
vote_house int(1), vote_date int(5), vote_year int(2), bill_id varchar(8),
member_lastname varchar(50), vote_value varchar(10));
"""
    cur.execute(SQL)
    print "\nCreate ny_votes.\n"

def rst():
    SQL = """DROP TABLE ny_votes"""
    cur.execute(SQL)
    print "\nDropped ny_votes.\n"
    crt()

def addFile(fn):
    """parse and add all records in a file"""
    n = 0
    for votes in v.floor_vote_file(fn).iterVotes():
        for record in votes.iterRecords():
            add(record)
        n += 1
        print 'sucessfully added vote # ' + str(n)

def addAllFiles():
    for file in files:
        addFile(file)

if __name__=='__main__':
    rst()
    addAllFiles()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generators are a good idea, but you seem to miss the biggest problem:

(str for str in splitter.split(**open(fn).read()**) if str and str <> 'A' and str <> 'S')

You're reading the whole file in at once even if you only need to work with bits at a time. You're code is too complicated for me to fix, but you should be able to use file's iterator for your task:

(line for line in open(fn))

Comment: Agreed.  The code is pretty convoluted.  Any chance you (Blair) could rewrite the code to parse the file a line at time using the file "readline()" function. That might alleviate some problems if "data.txt" or other files are large.

Comment: Ah, ok--thank you!  I didn't know the I could use the file's iterator.  That is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you use a lot of slit() calls. This is memory consuming, according to http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2006-January/031571.html . You can start investigating this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment out `add(record)` to see if the problem is in your code or on the database side. All the records are added in one transaction (if supported) and maybe this leads to a problem if it get too many records. If commenting out `add(record)` helps, you could try to call `commit()` from time to time.

Comment: Terrific, thank you very much.  I changed the code to commit after each add and the problem seems to be solved.  Fantastico!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Python memory issue, but perhaps it's worth thinking about.  The previous answers make me think you'll sort that issue out quickly.

I wonder about the rollback logs in MySQL.  If a single transaction is too large, perhaps you can checkpoint chunks.  Commit each chunk separately instead of trying to rollback a 15MB file's worth.

Comment: Thanks for your insight--this appears to have been a part of the problem.  I changed my code to commit after adding each small record and the problem seemsto have disappeared.